# WebFluxTest cannot read matrix variables

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am writing a WebFluxTest :

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers=Example.class)

class ExampleTest  {
    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
    @Test
    public void example(){

        webTestClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/example/employees/id=1")
                     .exchange()
                     .expectBody().consumeWith(response -> assertTrue(new String(response.getResponseBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).contains(expected)));
    }
}
```

The code to be tested is:

```
@Controller
public class Example {

    @GetMapping("/example/employees/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String example(@MatrixVariable("id") int id) {
        ....
    }
```

It is a Spring Boot application with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
...
```

The output is:
"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Missing matrix variable 'id' for method parameter of type int"}

Comment: it may help the community to answer your question by what your code does

Comment: Since you have defined only the Example.class to be tested, it doesnt load your bean, is my best guess

Comment: Hi, Thomas and Con, please see my own answer below. I got a good advice from Spring Community. The problem is @WebFluxTest ignores the WebMvcConfigurer. I need to use@SpringBootTest instead. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
 @AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class Example {

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @Test
    public void example (){
        WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                     .baseUrl("http://localhost:"+port+"/example /employees/id=1").build();
        String expected = String.format("Received request id = [%d]\n", 1);
        webTestClient.get().exchange()
                       .expectBody().consumeWith(response -> assertTrue(new String(response.getResponseBody(),
                                               StandardCharsets.UTF_8).contains(expected)));
    }
```

I asked the Spring Community. Someone suggested me not to use @WebFluxTest to test the mvc controller. My mvc controller is not a web flux controller.
Also, @WebFluxTest ignores the WebMvcConfigurer.
I need to load the whole Spring boot application as the above code.